# Как оптимизировать базу данных?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть высоко нагруженная БД для букмекерской конторы. В которой ежесекундно обновляются тысячи событий.

Событие = матч.
В событии есть много различных коэффициентов. Победа первой команды, победа второй, Тоталы и т.д. Таких рынков коэффициентов порой доходит до тысячи.

Основной вопрос это архитектурный.
На данный момент у каждого события есть столбец longtext, где хранится огромный JSON со всеми рынками коэффициентов.

Вот хотелось бы понять как построить более производительную архитектуру. Продолжить ли хранить все коэффициенты в JSON, или создать отдельную таблицу где будут храниться все коэффициенты всех событий по отдельности. т.е. если у события 900 типов коэффициентов то создать 900 строк в новой таблице, куда их всех записать.

По поводу выборки по JSON то она не нужна.

Тут еще интересует не мало важный момент постоянного обновления коэффициентов. Если JSON можно просто обновить, то тут придется зацепить все 900 коэффициентов, сравнить их с новыми, и если они не совпадают то заменить. Запросов к БД получится огромное множество.
Конечно было бы намного удобнее если всё разделить, но будет ли это быстрее чем отправить один жирный запрос?

Тут еще суть в том что событий могут быть тысячи, а у каждого события коэффициентов под тысячу, и в дабавок всё это обновляется очень часто ~2-5 сек. (сила парсеров =))

Коротко о БД: Postgres расположенная в RDS amazon

Вроде всё что хотел написал, нужны любые советы по проектированию такой БД) Как лучше, что быстрее и т.д.

Спасибо всем кто откликнется =)

Comment: Если JSON является для вас более удобным / родным форматом данных, то может стоит хранить данные в MongoDB или в подобных?

Comment: Слишком много неизвестных факторов чтобы дать ответ. Начиная с того, какие операции будут выполнятся, далее как часто каждый вид операции и заканчивая структурой нагрузки (т.е. сколько паралельных операций каждого типа будет выполнятся). Далее, даже зная все это предсказать, что будет быстрее - запрос который достает 900 маленьких записей или запрос достающий одну + ее парсинг невозможно, т.к. зависит от таких параметров как скорость локального процессора, скорость сети и мощность сервера БД.

Comment: Боюсь единственный путь - реализовывать как проще + покрытие функциональными тестами (чтобы можно было изменить не опасаясь регрессий). Далее тестирование с симулированием нагрузки (либо реальной если возможно) и эксперименты.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ зависит от того как вы используете базу данных. 
Если только для хранения и полной выборки то используйте ваш Json, если вы слишком часто ковыряете Json извините за сравнение, то есть смысл разбить по таблицам.

Я думаю у Вас на определённый момент времени идет большая нагрузка на один объект, то есть смысл использовать Redis на этот период, а по окончании единижды слить в Postgres.